# When pushing to OpenShift I get pre-receive hook declined

Tags: git, openshift

I'm having trouble pushing to my OpenShift account. On first push I got this:

```
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 321 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Not stopping cartridge nodejs because hot deploy is enabled
remote: Not stopping cartridge mongodb because hot deploy is enabled
remote: No such file or directory - /var/lib/openshift/54f614834387ec5dbe000201/app-deployments/2015-04-30_16-45-12.229/repo/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/user-home
To ssh://54f614834387ec5dbe000201@nodejs-fightersconnect.rhcloud.com/~/git/nodejs.git/
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://54f614834387ec5dbe000201@nodejs-abcaaaa.rhcloud.com/~/git/nodejs.git/'
```

Now when I push my git reports 'Everything is up to date' but my changes are not populated. It seems like an issue with OpenShift but I haven't received any response from them yet. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Rather than downvoting blindly at least give some reason so I can improve or rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

Weird, so all of your changes are committed, but something failed on the remote side of things?

If that's the case I would try re-deploying the changes using [OpenShift's deployment and rollback options](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html). Basically, use `rhc deployment list -a <app>` to get a list of recent deployment sha1's, use `rhc deployment show <deployment_id> -a <app>` to view the details of that deployment (optional), and then use `rhc deploy <deployment_id> -a <app>` to re-deploy the deployment that failed.

```
$ rhc deployment list -a <app>
$ rhc deployment show <deployment_id> -a <app>
$ rhc deploy <deployment_id> -a <app>
```

Check out [option #2](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html#_option_2) for full details on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was not pushing to git correctly, I was push using the command `git push origin master` when I was suppose to use just `git push`

**example:**

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```